# how to get multiple files path in an array

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

i want to upload multiple pdf files in one file upload control in asp.net and then merg it ,
this is already done when i pass static path and file name 
how to do that dynamically 
my code is here

```
  if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
            {
                try
                {
                     HttpFileCollection uploadedVideoFiles = Request.Files;

                    // Get the HttpFileCollection

                    for (int i = 0; i < uploadedVideoFiles.Count; i++)
                    {
                        HttpPostedFile hpfiles = uploadedVideoFiles[i];
                      string fname = Path.GetFileName(hpfiles.FileName);

                        if (hpfiles.ContentLength > 0)
                        {
                            hpfiles.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Images/") + Path.GetFileName(hpfiles.FileName));
                            hpfiles.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(Path.Combine(@"~/Images/", fname)));
                            string filepath = Server.MapPath(@"~/Images/");
                            string path = filepath + fname;
                        }
                    }
                    String[] files = @"C:\ENROLLDOCS\A1.pdf,C:\ENROLLDOCS\A@.pdf".Split(',');
                    MergeFiles(@"C:\ENROLLDOCS\New1.pdf", files);// merg is a method which merg 2 or more than 2 documents
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Label1.Text = "The file could not be uploaded. The following error occured: " + ex.Message;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to collect values of `path` in a `List<string>` and then pass the result to `MergeFiles()`.

I don't quite follow your code (you'll need to clean it up a bit), but what you need is basically this:

```
var fileNames =
    uploadedVideoFiles.
        Select(uvf => {
            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(hpfiles.FileName);
            var destinatonPath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/images"), fileName);

            uvf.SaveAs(destinatonPath);

            return destinationPath;
        }).
        ToArray();

MergeFiles(@"C:\ENROLLDOCS\New1.pdf", fileNames);
```

Beware of duplicating file names in `~/images`, though.